# Install Git within Android Studio Giraffe on Apple MacBook Pro M2 - Ventura 13.0

Tags: android, git, macos, android-studio, macbookpro

I am new to Mac OS and hence struggling to install git in android studio.
Firstly i tried clicking download and install on the popup shown in android studio
[image: see this image]

After i do this error shows up

```
Failed to start Git process: Cannot run program "/usr/local/bin/git" (in directory "."): error=86, Bad CPU type in executable
```

And terminal ,
when i checked git --version . it shows up version and which git command gives this location of git

```
/usr/local/bin/git
```

but i cant see the git folder anywhere in finder. Now , in android studio settings when i test git giving this path it shows the same error.

i tried to install homebrew . But it gives me error too after 28 seconds - Operation timed out.

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was happening due to incompatability of apps within intel and M2 .Installing rosetta solved the issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).